# What is wrong with my double pulse test Ltspice schematic? Gate pulse is not getting generated when I connect the gate driver for 800V application

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, mosfet-driver, isolation

[image]

What is wrong with my double pulse test LTspice schematic? Gate pulse is not getting generated when I connect the gate driver for 800V application. Any connection error?

Comment: U2 has its gate shorted to its source. So are you using it for its body diode?

Comment: yes for using body diode (free wheeling interval)

Comment: What does "gate pulse is not getting generated" mean, exactly?

Comment: Input as you can see microcontroller pulse 3.3V but.. at Output B no voltage is coming

Comment: Have you tried running it longer than 10us? Maybe like 500ms? You’ll have to delay your PWL pulse too or [make it do a forever repeat](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-piecewise-linear-functions-for-voltage-current-sources.html).  The gate driver IC might need some time to “bootup” (i.e. get out of reset).

Comment: thankyou so much @SteKulov .. It worked! Where are can I find the information about bootup in the gate driver data sheet? Never came across it...

Comment: It’s in section “6.10 Switching Characteristics”.  There’s also a plot in Section 7.5.